# How do I remove these error messages in JSON settings

Tags: json

I am new to code & I am trying to fix these errors in the image. I appreciate the help in advance.

**JSON Settings Code**

[image: JSON Settings Code]

---

Is this a better reference?

```
{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Company/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Property suppressShowKeyBindingsNotice is not allowed.",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 40
}
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code - post the code.

Comment: My bad, I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

U missed comma at the end of line no 27 and some other lines

**Error:**

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\PHP\\:php.exe"
```

**Expected:**

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\PHP\\:php.exe",
```

Comment: is that after the {  ?

Comment: L:27 should be "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\PHP\\:php.exe",

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, what about the other errors?

Comment: its too long to post here

Comment: {
 "resource": "/C:/Users/Company/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json",
 "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
 "code": "1",
 "severity": 4,
 "message": "Value is not accepted. Valid values: \"Default\", \"Jedi\", \"JediLSP\", \"Pylance\", \"None\".",
 "startLineNumber": 20,
 "startColumn": 30,
 "endLineNumber": 20,
 "endColumn": 41
}

Comment: This from the bottom where I copied the error message & this is what it gives me

Comment: {
 "resource": "/C:/Users/Company/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json",
 "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
 "severity": 4,
 "message": "Property suppressShowKeyBindingsNotice is not allowed.",
 "startLineNumber": 5,
 "startColumn": 9,
 "endLineNumber": 5,
 "endColumn": 40
}

Comment: Is that the same for this one too?